# Can you explain this simple example from chapter 3 of the Django book (it is about views, url patterns, and regular expressions)?

Tags: regex, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to follow what is being explained here: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/ (the confusing example is about 4/5 of the way down the page).

The idea is to have a URL in which any one of `/time/plus/1`, `/time/plus/2`, `/time/plus/3` etc -- all the way up to `/time/plus/99` -- could be matched.  The book says:

> How, then do we design our application to handle arbitrary hour
>   offsets? The key is to use wildcard URLpatterns. As we mentioned
>   previously, a URLpattern is a regular expression; hence, we can use
>   the regular expression pattern \d+ to match one or more digits:

Since we want to stop at 99, the book suggests using the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    (r'^time/plus/\d{1,2}/$', hours_ahead),
    # ...
)
```

But now we are faced with the problem of capturing exactly which number the regular expression matches and using it in our calculations.  The book's explanation proceeds:

> Now that we’ve designated a wildcard for the URL, we need a way of
>   passing that wildcard data to the view function, so that we can use a
>   single view function for any arbitrary hour offset. We do this by
>   placing parentheses around the data in the URLpattern that we want to
>   save. In the case of our example, we want to save whatever number was
>   entered in the URL, so let’s put parentheses around the `\d{1,2}`, like
>   this:

```
(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

> If you’re familiar with regular expressions, you’ll be right at home
>   here; we’re using parentheses to capture data from the matched text.

Okay, I understand that the data is being captured -- but where is it being stored?  How does Django know that it needs to pass the captured data to the `hours_ahead` function?  Indeed, one commentator on the books website even asks the following question:

> It's not clear from the description how saving the number entered in
>   the URL - by putting parentheses around d{1,2} - allows this value to
>   be passed as a parameter to hours_ahead.

Can you explain how the captured data from the URL get's passed to the hours_ahead function?

In case you're interested, here is the function from the views.py file:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
import datetime

def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses form what is called a regular expression [capturing group](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Group.html), as you allude to in your question.

I don't have the Django code in front of me, but you could actually do something like this yourself using the `re` module and an [asterisk](http://www.technovelty.org/code/python/asterisk.html).

```
import re

def myfunc1arg(arg1):
    print "I got passed the argument", arg1

def myfunc2args(arg1, arg2):
    print "I got passed the arguments", arg1, "and", arg2

myfunc1arg(*re.match("args/(.*)", "args/hello").groups())

myfunc2args(*re.match("args/(.*)/(.*)", "args/hello/world").groups())
```

The first argument to re.match is the regular expression (the pattern you are putting in your code) and the second argument is the "url". Django uses a line of code like the above to pull out the groups in parentheses (the capturing groups) and pass them to your function.

ETA: If you're interested, [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/urlresolvers.py) (lines 195-209) is the specific Django code that captures the regular expressions from the URL path:

```
def resolve(self, path):
    match = self.regex.search(path)
    if match:
        # If there are any named groups, use those as kwargs, ignoring
        # non-named groups. Otherwise, pass all non-named arguments as
        # positional arguments.
        kwargs = match.groupdict()
        if kwargs:
            args = ()
        else:
            args = match.groups()
        # In both cases, pass any extra_kwargs as **kwargs.
        kwargs.update(self.default_args)

        return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
```

What it has there in the ResolverMatch are `args`, a list of positional arguments, and `kwargs`, a list of keyword arguments (which can be created via [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)).

Comment: Thanks.  This was a really great explanation.  I learned a lot and there is plenty here for me to digest.

Answer (score 1):

For regular expressions in general, brackets `()` indicate that the portion of the string that matches the regex inside the brackets (in this case `(\d{1,2})`) is *captured*.

By *captured*, I mean that it is saved so that it can be retrieved later.

This is commonly used in (e.g.) find/replace operations: say I wanted to turn "I am 39 years old" to "Ewww, you're 39!". We have to not only *match* `I am xx years old`, but also *capture* the 39 so that we can use it later.

Typically then, you could do a find/replace with find being `I am (\d{1,2}) years old`, and replace with `Ewww, you're \1!`. The brackets in the find expression mean "save whatever is in these brackets because we want to use it later", and the `\1` in the replace expression means "put the first thing we saved back in here."

For Django, `(r'some.regex.here.including.parentheses',FUNCTION)` means that anything that is saved (ie surrounded by brackets) in the regex is passed as an argument to the function.